# I need a word to describe a person who seeks information for other people?

Tags: grammaticality

Im looking for another word to call a person who seeks and finds information for others.

Comment: You could call such a person a *researcher*.

Comment: Like a detective?

Comment: A ***lmgtfyer*.**

Comment: I think you meant [lmgtfyer](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=lmgtfyer).

Comment: A _Nosy Parker_.

Comment: "Researcher" is the term traditionally used for someone who, eg, looks up facts for editorial writers, newscasters, and other "public facing" individuals.

Answer (score 2):

*Private [Investigator](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/investigator)*:

> noun
>
> A person who carries out a formal inquiry or investigation:

Answer (score 0):

Prying(noun: pries) or inquisitive